# ¿Cómo puedo diferenciar dos valores iguales para que hagan diferentes cosas en un IF?

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy haciendo un userform para ingresar las calificaciones de diferentes personas en diferentes actividades. Para las actividades estoy usando un ComboBox y para las personas estoy usando el comando `Set Label = Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")` añadiendo así desde la tabla de excel el nombre de la persona y de la misma manera(`Set Text = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")`) el cuadro de texto para poner numéricamente la nota.

Para que los datos aparezcan en la tabla cuando dé la orden con un Botón de comando estoy usando un If que me reconozca si el valor del ComboBox y el de la celda donde está el dato de esa opción del ComboBox es el mismo, finalmente cuando "detecte" si es el mismo añadiré la calificación a la correspondiente celda con el código  `Controls("text" & a).Text` todo esto usando diferentes For para que selecciona la celda y el dato que se debe de ingresar(la a del ultimo código descrito por ejemplo).

Esto ya lo logré, mi problema actualmente es que si 2 o más valores del ComboBox y por lo tanto de la tabla comparten el mismo texto se llenan automáticamente todas las celdas que concuerden(como se muestra en la imagen) y esto es lo que quiero evitar.

Estoy atento, muchas gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Por qué hay 3 biologías? Si son biologías diferentes, tu mejor y más fácil opción es diferenciarlas en plan "Biología I, Biología II, etc.". Si son la misma Biología, te sobran 2 columnas. No es posible diferenciar 2 valores iguales, precisamente porque son iguales.

Comment: En este caso es porque es un ejemplo, sí son exactamente la misma capacitación, y pues está 3 veces porque se supone que se hace varias veces en el año para "afianzar" el conocimiento. Pero teniendo en cuenta tu respuesta sí es mejor nombrarlas de manera diferente en vez de complicarme.

Comment: También quería intentarlo por la práctica, estoy aprendiendo. Muchas gracias Esei :)